# Search a file by filename and use the result to search new files - Powershell

Tags: powershell

Have an issue in using my search results. I search a folder recursivly to bring me all files that are greater than 3 kb. Then i need to use the name of those files in order to find all files that have similar name and copy all of them in a new folder.
the root dirextory contains:

```
folder1: 0050

DLD1900394819102600500001_a.txt 7kb

DLD1900394819102600500001_b.txt 1kb 

DLD1900394819102600500001_c.txt 1kb

DLD1900394819102600500151_a.txt 1kb

DLD1900394819102600500151_b.txt 1kb

folder2: 0051

DLD1900394819102600500002_a.txt 7kb

DLD1900394819102600500002_b.txt 1kb 

DLD1900394819102600500002_c.txt 1kb 

DLD1900394819102600500122_a.txt 1kb 

DLD1900394819102600500122_b.txt 1kb
```

so by using this

```
$Path  = "C:\test\"
$test = Get-ChildItem $Path  -recurse | 
    where-object {$_.length -gt 3000} | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.basename.replace("_a","")}
```

**I find all greater than 3 kb remove the  "_a" char and
I have those two as result in an object**

```
DLD1900394819102600500001

DLD1900394819102600500002
```

**,but how to search all folders again in order to select and copy**

```
DLD1900394819102600500001*.*

DLD1900394819102600500002*.*
```

**to a new folder???**

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -recurse -File | where-object {$_.length -gt 3000}  | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -Filter ($_.basename.replace("_a","")) -File}
```

You already have the filename, just pass it to Get-ChildItem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question.  Is this what you're looking for?

```
#Original code
$Path = 'C:\test'
$BaseNames = 
    ((Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse) | 
        Where-Object{$_.Length -gt 3000}|
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName) |
                ForEach-Object{$_.Replace('_a','')}

#Use Regular expression to filter names
$regexBaseNames = ''
ForEach($name in $BaseNames){$regexBaseNames += "^$name.*[.].+|"}
#Remove pipe from end of regex expression
$regexBaseNames = $regexBaseNames.Substring(0,$regexBaseNames.Length - 1)
#Get files whose name matches regex expression
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | 
    Where-Object{$_.Name -match $regexBaseNames}
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, could you please elaborate a little more concerning what you are trying to do and why you need to do it?  That may help answer your question.

Note 1: String building the way I did can be very resource-intensive.  If you have a lot of base names to append to the string, consider either using the StringBuilder .NET class.

Note 2: 
You may want to consider building an array of BaseNames to pass to the -Filter PowerShell parameter, then performing the actions on each base name individually.  If you decide use the Filter method (which PowerShell can usually perform much faster than piping to Where-Object when thousands of files are involved), you could also pass all files into a single array list, then perform the actions need on them with a ForEach loop.

I will give examples of these suggestions if you need me to and I find your problem would benefit from any of them.

Comment: let me explain a bit more.in test path there are hundreds of folders like 0050 that contain hundreds of  txt files. Firstly, i want to locate all files in folders that are >5 kb like DLD1900394819102600500001_a.txt 7kb,DLD1900394819102600500002_a.txt (all have the * _a.txt  format). Then i need to isolate their format like this DLD1900394819102600500001,DLD1900394819102600500002  **and search again all folders on C:\test to find all files that have this form** DLD1900394819102600500001*.* ,DLD1900394819102600500001*.*, regardless their size and copy them to a new folder.

Comment: on the second step after isolateting my new search format i have a list of names DLD1900394819102600500001,DLD1900394819102600500002 how do i use em to search all folders again to find file names with the format DLD1900394819102600500001*.* or DLD1900394819102600500002*.* and so on.